# How to add Paypal pay later message on google AMP

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal, amp-html

How to add paypal pay later message on AMP pages ?

I am using this -
on head

```
<script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
```

on file

```
<amp-script layout="container" script="hello-world" class="sample">
<div id="pp-pay-later-message"></div>
</amp-script>
<script id="hello-world" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
console.log("helo---from amp script");
const messageElement = document.getElementById('pp-pay-later-message');
const price = 500;
paypal
  .Messages({
    amount: price,
    style: {
      layout: "text",
      logo: {
        type: "primary",
      },
    },
  })
  .render(messageElement);
paypal.Messages.render(messageElement)
</script>
```

But nothing display

Anyone have idea how to show a message ?

Comment: you need  a user action.

Comment: @JayGray what is user action here ?

Comment: Button - some element that requires an action by the user. In most cases `amp-script` does not have a default action (e.g. print a message). To see a message, the user must take an action to display the message.